# Remove all tabs, blank/brake/new lines, empty lines, multiple successive spaces except single space character

Tags: regex

I have a HTML code that looks like this:

```
   <TABLE>
      <TR>
        <TD>Item</TD>
        <TD><A>48</A> 
                    </TD></TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Item</TD>
        <TD><A >48</A> 
                    </TD></TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Tags</TD>
        <TD><A> 
          keyword</A>, <A>keyword 
          </A>, <A>keyword
          </A>, <A>keyword</A>, <A 
          >keyword</A>, <A 
          >keyword 
          </A>, <A>keyword 
           </A>             
   </TABLE>
```

Using *.NET* regex, can anyone help me to remove *ALL* whitespace characters *EXCEPT* single space characters from it so that I will end up with one long string of code?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to remove a streak of 2 or more consecutive spaces? The HTML may not render the same as what you have originally. For example, `two__space` will get collapsed into `twospace` (`_` represent space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[\p{Z}\s]{2,}
```

This will check if there are at least 2 whitespace characters. Replace with empty string if found.

`\p{Z}` stands for `All Separators` Unicode shorthand class.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cp%7bZ%7d%5cs%5d%7b2%2c%7d&i=%3cTABLE%3e%0d%0a++++++%3cTR%3e%0d%0a++++++++%3cTD%3eItem%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a++++++++%3cTD%3e%3cA%3e48%3c%2fA%3e+%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++%3c%2fTD%3e%3c%2fTR%3e%0d%0a++++++%3cTR%3e%0d%0a++++++++%3cTD%3eItem%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a++++++++%3cTD%3e%3cA+%3e48%3c%2fA%3e+%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++%3c%2fTD%3e%3c%2fTR%3e%0d%0a++++++%3cTR%3e%0d%0a++++++++%3cTD%3eTags%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a++++++++%3cTD%3e%3cA%3e+%0d%0a++++++++++keyword%3c%2fA%3e%2c+%3cA%3ekeyword+%0d%0a++++++++++%3c%2fA%3e%2c+%3cA%3ekeyword%0d%0a++++++++++%3c%2fA%3e%2c+%3cA%3ekeyword%3c%2fA%3e%2c+%3cA+%0d%0a++++++++++%3ekeyword%3c%2fA%3e%2c+%3cA+%0d%0a++++++++++%3ekeyword+%0d%0a++++++++++%3c%2fA%3e%2c+%3cA%3ekeyword+%0d%0a+++++++++++%3c%2fA%3e+++++++++++++%0d%0a+++%3c%2fTABLE%3e&r=)

Comment: The regex is overly complicated for this task.

Comment: I'm not sure why you insist on this convoluted solution, when the look-ahead can be removed and the regex can be simplified by changing the quantifier into `{2,}`

Comment: I do not insist. I only suggest. Using this solution, we can control which whitespace we want to keep. a regular space, or a hard space. With `\s{2,}` you won't have the flexibility.

Comment: FYI, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WhitespaceCharacter `\s` includes `\p{Z}`.

Comment: @nhahtdh: You are definitely helpful, where should I upvote :) ? I had issues with just `\s` or `\p{Z}`, I usually combined them to play it safe. Now, I see that it also may depend on the ECMAScript option. If it is enabled, `\s` does not include `\p{Z}`.

Comment: Just upvote my comment if you find it helpful. It is rather a curious case with .NET regex, as  `\p{Z}` works even when ECMAScript flag is set, and so are balancing groups.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the following regex,

```
\s{2,} // \s will match all whitespaces, and {2,} tells it, there needs to be more then 1
```

You can use it in c# like this:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s{2,}", "");
```

Effect:

[image]

Comment: Rather than removing them, I think it is more accurate to replace multiple consecutive spaces with a single space.

Comment: But the question states: "remove ALL white spaces EXCEPT single space characters", and that is excactly what this code does.